# C++ why does this not provide the system maximum size for integer?

Tags: c++, c, integer, bit-manipulation

So, if I understand correctly, an integer is a collection of bytes, it represents numbers in base-two format, if you will.

Therefore, if I have unsigned int test=0, is should really just consist of a field of bits, all of which are zero.  However,

```
unsigned int test=0;
test=~test;
```

produces **-1**.

I would've thought that this would've filled all the bits with `'1'`, making the integer as large as it can be on that system....

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `-1` *is* the largest unsigned integer. What's the problem?

Comment: It all depends on what exactly you mean by _produces_. How do you check/output/print the result?

Comment: I suppose you are using `printf` and not `std::cout` to print the result. So this should be tagged C and not C++

Comment: Sounds like you're invoking UB by passing the wrong type of data to printf. The real problem here is: Which manual tells you that passing an unsigned int to correspond to a %d format specifier is ok?

Comment: This is for a micro-controller... so I *really* care about efficiency/finding out the actual size.  But yes, @qdii, I was using printf... but the behavior is the same in C++...

Comment: Same behaviour in C++? If you are using `printf` with a wrong parameter, perhaps, but I don’t believe `std::cout << a` will write a negative sign on screen if `a` is `unsigned`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How do you print the value?

If it's displayed as "-1" or a large unsigned integer is just a manner of the bits are *interpreted* when printing them out, the bits themselves don't know the difference.

You need to print it as an `unsigned` value.

Also, as pointed out by other answers, you're assming a lot about how the system stores the numbers; there's no guarantee that there's a specific correlation between a number and the bits used to represent that number.

Anyway, the proper way to get this value is to [`#include <climits>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) and then just use `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: Use `%u` instead of `%d` in `printf`

Comment: what about using `std::numeric_limits` ?

Comment: Wow, thanks guys.  That cleared it up.  I'm interested in programming this to operate on a micro-controller, so I don't want to use and #includes I needn't absolutely must.  Testing on a microcomputer, so this all helps.  Thanks!

Comment: @user1833028 why? I believe `<climits>` will just add a couple defines, it should not affect the code size.

Comment: When I looked at the code I just saw predefines yes... but how does that help compute the size of the integer on a system that may not COME with limits.h... not sure if mine does or not lol

Comment: Well, integer types shall be "using a pure binary representation" according to the C and C++ standards (for the value bits, the sign bit is special in signed integer types), so modulo as-if, and ignoring possible padding bits, you can assume quite a bit about the representation of integer types.

Answer (score 4):

You're not understanding correctly. An integer represents an integer, and that's it. The specifics of the representation are not part of the standard (with a few exceptions), and you have no business assuming any correlation between bitwise operations and integer values.

(Ironically, what the standard *does* mandate via modular arithmetic rules is that `-1` converted to an unsigned integer *is* in fact the largest possible value for that unsigned type.)

*Update:* To clarify, I'm speaking generally for all integral types. If you only use *unsigned types* (which I assumed you weren't because of your negative answer), you have a well-defined correspondence between bitwise operations and the represented value.

Comment: There should be a machine-aware fork of C/C++ standard. So many people rely on compiler-specific behaviour that it should be standardised.

Comment: "you have no business assuming any correlation between bitwise operations and integer values." is wrong. With a few exceptions (the corner cases where you get UB or implementation defined results), bitwise operations have nothing to do with the underlying representation.

Comment: @Kos: Rather, a machine-aware part of SO where people who like to set their own bits can belabour the l33test tricks they've found.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I'm not speaking against bitwise operations. I'm speaking about the *correlation* between bitwise operations and the value of the integer that the object represents. You can certainly use any integral type as a bitfield all you like -- just don't ask what *number* the integer is!

Comment: @KerrekSB yes, and that correlation is well-defined. Given `std::uint32_t x = 0;`, ~x must be 0xFFFFFFFF, *regardless of the underlying representation*.

Comment: So *how* an integer represents a number may not be the field of bits I presume it to be?

Comment: How many systems still use something other than 2's complement?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: OK, fair enough, for unsigned integers you actually get pretty well-defined behaviour. I exaggerated a bit to avoid any quibbles about *signed* values mostly. Indeed, something like left shift *is* well-defined as "times two", as long as you only use unsigned types.

Comment: I have been on a programming hiatus, and I forgot about some of the issues this has brought up... so really, thanks guys.

Comment: @KerrekSB If “The specifics of the representation are not part of the standard” were true even for signed integer types, then clause 6.2.6.2 in the C99 standard would have been much shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use:

```
unsigned int test =0;
test--;
```